# What is the $f(t,y)$ in this question?

Tags: numerical-methods

[image]

Euler's method requires $f(t,y)$. What's the $f(t,y)$ function in this assignment? $q(t)$ and $p(t)$ are vectors. How am I supposed to apply them in Euler's method?

Comment: Usually, yes, the general formulation of Euler's method uses some $f(t,y)$. If you want to understand it will enough to set it up yourself, however, what's more important to think about and focus on is what's on the _other side_ of that equality sign: $y'(t)$. What is $y$? Once you have a good answer to that, you can just differentiate and find your $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Your unknown functions are $q_1,q_2,p_1,p_2$ the text already gives you a system of differential equations for these functions
\begin{align}
\dot{q}_1(t) &= p_1(t)\\
\dot{q}_2(t) &= p_2(t) \\
\dot{p}_1(t) &=\frac{-1}{\big(q_1(t)^2 + q_2(t)^2\big)^\frac{3}{2}} q_1(t) \\
\dot{p}_2(t) &= \frac{-1}{\big(q_1(t)^2 + q_2(t)^2\big)^\frac{3}{2}} q_1(t)
\end{align}
So your $y(t)$ is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} q_1(t) \\ q_2(t) \\ p_1(t) \\ p_2(t) \end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $f(t,y)$ is given by the right hand side of the differential equation.